# How can I bind the operations tuple with the set_operazioni?

Tags: indexing, constraints, cplex

I have this job shop problem: a set of jobs and for each job I have to specify the release date, the due dates and a set of operations. For each operation I have to specify the type of machines needed, the processing time and the number of operators. How can I do this in CPEX and then how do I manage the various indices to define the constraints? Thank you.

For example I wrote this:

```
tuple job 
    {

   int release_date;

   int due_date;

   int set_operazioni;

 }
 
 tuple operazioni
 {
   int macchine;

   int processamento;

   int operatori; 

 }
```

But, how can I bind the operations tuple with the set_operazioni?
I hope I had a good time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

within a tuple you may use a set of int:

```
tuple job {

int release_date;

int due_date;

{int} set_operazioni;

}

{job} jobs={<1,10,{1,2,3}>};

execute
{
  writeln(jobs);
}
```

or you may use subtuple

```
tuple operazioni { int macchine;

int processamento;

int operatori;

}

{operazioni} seto={<1,1,1>,<2,2,2>};

tuple job {

int release_date;

int due_date;

operazioni o;

}

{job} jobs with o in seto ={<1,10,<1,1,1>>,<1,10,<2,2,2>>};

execute
{
  writeln(jobs);
}
```

Comment: Okay but for each operation I have to specify the type of machines, the processing time and the number of operators. How could I do it? I'm new to cplex